# Java 7 ImageIO can fail to read and write in Windows 7 due to permissions problems

Tags: java, windows, permissions

I had a program running in Windows 7 64 bit using Java 6 which fails using Java 7. ImageIO it seems makes temporary cache files when reading and writing. In my Eclipse IDE, ImageIO now hangs with no error messsage. In another machine, I get an IOException permission denied.

The workaround I've adopted is to read the image using Toolkit.createImage and convert to a BufferedImage. This doesn't seem to need to create any files but is clunky. I am now writing by converting to a byte array.

Is anyone else having these problems?

Comment: Well, have you checked the file or folder you're trying to write to isn't read-only?

Comment: *"Regards,"*  [SO is not a social network](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128552/155831), please don't include such noise in questions. *"Chris"* Better put as an edit to [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1368075/user1368075).

Answer (score 1):

I had a performance problem with those cached files and solved it by calling `javax.imageio.ImageIO.setUseCache(false)`. As long as the original image files are already on a disk already, there shouldn't be a performance penalty.